# How to do exceptional handling in Flink applications?

Tags: exception, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Want to implement the exceptional handling for errors and exceptions,how to achieve it? is there any document for this?

I search on this but I haven't find any official documentation for this.

Comment: More context would be useful. Are you interested in how to handle errors returned from the job execution, or errors in specific operators?

Comment: interested in how to handle errors returned from the job execution.

Comment: Usually You just let Flink restart the application, instead of handling that. Can You provide some info on Your use-case, so we can better understand the problem ??